# Literal meaning of 無奇不有

Tags: idioms

The correct meaning of 無奇不有 would be: full of extraordinary/bizarre things. But why don't the individual characters not add up to the intended meaning?

This is not the only idiom that I found difficulty in understanding the word per word meaning.

Answer (score 4):

無 - no

奇 - strange (thing)

不 - not

有 - exist

無奇不有 = no strange thing does not exist (nothing is too strange to exist)

Comment: in 平平無奇: 無 = 'not (adv)' , 奇 = 'extraordinary (adj)' = ordinary ; in 無奇不有: 無 = 'no (preposition)' , 奇 = 'strange thing (n)'

Comment: I was thinking about 'No strange not have' and got perplexed. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

无奇不有: 什么稀奇的事物都有。

无奇不有
not rare not there
There are all kinds of rare, strange and wonderful things.

> But why don't the individual characters not [sic] add up to the intended
> meaning?

"Pigs might fly." says nothing about pigs.

Or "You can add up the parts, but won't get the whole" because idioms don't work that way.